# how to do kruskal-wallis test with variables that are not exact (< or >) in R

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

I have three groups on which I have performed a Kruskal-Wallis test in R. The data is as follows

```
A = c(178.53, 226.87,219.78)
B = c(<16.00,   <16.00, <16.00)   
C = c(<16.00,   <16.00, <16.00)

dat = list(g1=A, g2=B, g3=C)

kruskal.test(dat)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error: Unexpected '<' in B and C. How can I deal with variables that
>   have "<" symbol.

Comment: please clarify your question. It is unclear if `c(<16.00,   <16.00, <16.00)` is what you data looks like or if you are adding these `<`s. This vector does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to correct how you organize your data. In your case all the <16 are simply 16. The less thans are treated as ties regardless of their numerical value as they are numerically less than the smallest non-censored value (i.e., all the 16's need to be a single number less than 178.53) and you'll get the same answer.

```
test <- data.frame(Gp = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                   Y  = c(178.53, 226.87, 219.78, 16.00, 16.00, 
                          16.00, 16.00, 16.00, 16.00))

with(test, kruskal.test(Y~Gp))
```

Keep in mind that if your data set were

```
A = 178.53, 226.87, 219.78,   5
B = <16.00,   <16.00, <16.00, 5
C = <16.00,   <16.00, <16.00, 5
```

then you would need to re-code all the 5's in the same way as you code the <16's since you dont know whether 5 is > or < a "<16".